# Camel 3.5 Logger, Spring Boot and log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, logging, apache-camel, log4j2

I'm using Camel 3.5 and Spring Boot 2.3.4 app.
I'm trying to use log4j2 and config log levels and appenders in a log4j2.xml file.
It works from a Processor but not directly in a RouteDefinition.

```java
package org.example.builders;

import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.example.processors.Watch;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Builder extends RouteBuilder {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Builder.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("{{uri.quartz.debug}}")
                // OK
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOGGER,"${header.fireTime} - Quartz DEBUG 1")
                // NOK
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "${header.fireTime} - Quartz DEBUG 2")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${header.fireTime} - Quartz INFO")
                .log(LoggingLevel.TRACE, "${header.fireTime} - Quartz TRACE")
                .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "${header.fireTime} - Quartz WARN")
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "${header.fireTime} - Quartz ERROR")
                .process(new Watch())
                .to("mock:end");
    }
}
```

The processor class :

```java
package org.example.processors;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Watch implements Processor {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Watch.class.getName());
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
        LOGGER.log(Level.ALL, "LOGGER -> ALL");
        LOGGER.log(Level.TRACE, "LOGGER -> TRACE");
        LOGGER.log(Level.DEBUG, "LOGGER -> DEBUG");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "LOGGER -> INFO");
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARN, "LOGGER -> WARN");
        LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, "LOGGER -> ERROR");
        exchange.getMessage().setBody(body);
    }
}
```

He is the log4j2.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT"/>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="org.example.processors" level="trace"></Logger>
        <Logger name="org.example.builders" level="debug"></Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Here is the console output. Only Error log level is printed.
I have to call the method .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOGGER, to get what I want.

```
Tue Nov 17 18:28:10 CET 2020 - Quartz DEBUG 1
Tue Nov 17 18:28:10 CET 2020 - Quartz ERROR
LOGGER -> TRACE
LOGGER -> DEBUG
LOGGER -> INFO
LOGGER -> WARN
LOGGER -> ERROR
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to Luca Burgazzoli

In log4j2.xml

```
<Logger name="logging-route" level="debug"></Logger>
```

And in the dsl :

```
.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "logging-route", "${header.fireTime} - Quartz DEBUG 2")
```

The console Output :

```
Tue Nov 17 19:43:25 CET 2020 - Quartz DEBUG 1
Tue Nov 17 19:43:25 CET 2020 - Quartz DEBUG 2
Tue Nov 17 19:43:25 CET 2020 - Quartz ERROR
LOGGER -> TRACE
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the log eip takes the route name as log name, see https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/log-eip.html. To set the name using the java dsl, you can use something like .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "my-name", "${body}")

Comment: is that what you expect ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I had edited my post.
Thank you very much
You should post an answer so that I can validate it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, the log eip takes the route name as log name, see camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/log-eip.html. To set the name using the java dsl, you can use something like `.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "my-name", "${body}")`